# Basic security mistakes to avoid in C

Tags: c++, c, security

As a beginner to C, i want to know what are the basic security tips every C programmer should be familiar with. Strictly referring to C.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by *security*?

Comment: A full answer would probably be as long as the C++ spec itself.

Comment: Is it about C or about C++? Either way, the scope is rather broad.

Comment: The answer should be quite different for C and C++.

Comment: Well, the most obvious is that you shouldn't invest in a security with a single digit dollar price. C fell under that rule since the financial crisis started. But generally, you shouldn't ask for stock tips on Stack Overflow.

Comment: See the [CERT C Secure Coding Standard](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/CERT+C+Secure+Coding+Standard) for a decent starting point.  There are about 700 pages in the [book](http://www.informit.com/store/product.aspx?isbn=0321563212).

Comment: Crank all the way up the warning level of your compiler and **mind the warnings**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think that the main problem is [buffer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow).
It may happen using function like fgets, or scanf, without specifying the max number of bytes to read. A malicious input string larger than allocated buffer may overrite the return address in the stack causing the execution of the supplied exploit.

Answer (score 0):

The topic is quite large, but as a start, you may want to avoid segmentation faults and buffer overflows.

Comment: Well, that's the objective, you should explain how to achieve it. :)

Answer (score -1):

The most obvious one: buffer overruns. Use `strncpy` instead of `strcpy`.

Comment: `strncpy()` is no panacea - it does not guarantee null terminated strings, so it has to be used carefully.

Comment: `strncpy` simply should not be used by the vast majority of programmers. Unless you how to distinguish who should be using it, you're not one of the ones who should be using it. :-)